# Can't understand this behaviour of window implicit object

Tags: javascript

HTML code:

```
<html><body><pre><script src="pippo.js"></script></pre></body></html>
```

Javascript Code (file "pippo.js"):

```
document.writeln("start");
var f1 = function(){
    document.writeln('Hello, world! f1');
}

var f2 = function(){
    document.writeln('Hello, world! f2');
}
(window)
```

Output int the browser (i tryed Chrome and FF):

> Start
>   Hello, world! f2

Why is last defiend function executed?
if i add `a=0` f2 is not executed
so it seems to me that the last definition is evalueted
I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

A plain `function(){}()` is an invalid expression.
However, `function x(){}()` and `var x = function(){}();` are valid ones.

**In JavaScript, functions are invoked using parentheses.**

```
var f2 = function(){ document.writeln('Hello, world! f2'); }(window)
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^|      |
//             Function definition                          Invoke function
```

declares a variable `f2`, and assigns the return value of the function to it. It doesn't have any return value, so `f2` is `undefined`.

But, in your function, you're calling the `document.writeln` method, which prints a line of content in the document. That's the cause of your observed effect.

*(Your code could also have been written in this way):*

```
var some_function = function(){ document.writeln('Hello, world! f2'); };
var f2 = some_function(window);
```

---

If you want to use `(window)` on the next line, without invoking the function at the line of `f2`, you have to add a semicolon at the end of the line:

```
var f2 = function(){ document.writeln('Hello, world! f2'); };
(window); //                                                ^ Semicolon
```

Comment: If you add `a=0` to the end of file there should be no change, guess you add it between `f2 = ...` and `(window)`, in this case there is an error, that is being silenced by FF and Chrome, look at the console(F12).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i understand the problem.